# Java RSA key generation

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I was trying to understand how the RSA key generation works and therefore tried to implement it in Java. It's generating keys already, but when I'm encrypting and decrypting something using my generated keys it seems like my keys are wrong. This is my code to generate keys:

```
public void generateNewKeypair(int bit) {
    BigInteger[] primes = generatePrimes(2, bit / 2);
    BigInteger p = primes[0];
    BigInteger q = primes[1];
    modulo = q.multiply(p);
    BigInteger pN = (q.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1))).multiply(p.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1)));
    publicKey = BigInteger.ZERO;
    while (publicKey.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        BigInteger rnd = new BigInteger(pN.bitLength(), random);
        if (rnd.compareTo(pN) <= 0 && rnd.gcd(pN).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            publicKey = rnd;
        }
    }
    privateKey = publicKey.modInverse(modulo);
}
```

and thats the entire class: http://pastebin.com/DDQh2Q3n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your error:

```
    privateKey = publicKey.modInverse(modulo);
```

You need to compute this inverse mod (p-1)(q-1), which is your variable pN. So try

```
    privateKey = publicKey.modInverse(pN);
```

and see if you don't get better results.

Comment: Thanks alot, that fixed it :) Another question, do you have any idea how I could optimize my code?

Comment: Optimize? What part needs optimizing?

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what are you trying to do. Are you trying to understand how RSA key generation works or are you simply trying to write code to generate keys for an app?

For the second, I would highly recommend not trying to write your own code to generate keys as cryptography is very easy to get wrong. Use OpenSSL/Android NDK or such.

For the first, instead of handcoding a prime calculating function, use BigInteger.probablePrime and BigInteger.nextProbablePrime(lastprime). See an implementation here: http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/RSA-BigInteger-RsaKeyGenerator-java.html

Comment: I want to understand how it works and therefore I would like to know why my code is not working